# How to take part of a string without using Substring

Tags: c#

I want to take a specific part of an output string (the server name). It's working, but returning more characters then I need, and I only want the server name.

My code:

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c nslookup -type=mx gmail.com"; // Note the /c command (*)
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.Start();
        //* Read the output (or the error)
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();


        MessageBox.Show(output);

        string[] tokens = output.Split(' ');

        //take my server name
        string retVal = tokens[11];


        MessageBox.Show(retVal);
```

My output String:

```
Servidor:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

Não é resposta autoritativa:
hotmail.com     MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = mx3.hotmail.com//I WANT THIS STRING  "mx3.hotmail.com", the first name server
hotmail.com     MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = mx4.hotmail.com
hotmail.com     MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = mx1.hotmail.com
hotmail.com     MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = mx2.hotmail.com

mx4.hotmail.com internet address = 207.46.8.167
mx4.hotmail.com internet address = 65.54.188.126
mx4.hotmail.com internet address = 65.54.188.110
mx4.hotmail.com internet address = 65.54.188.94
mx4.hotmail.com internet address = 65.55.37.104
mx4.hotmail.com internet address = 65.55.92.184
mx4.hotmail.com internet address = 65.55.92.168
mx4.hotmail.com internet address = 65.55.33.119
mx4.hotmail.com internet address = 207.46.8.199
...
```

my retVal(variable name):

```
mx3.hotmail.com hotmail MX
```

I only want "mx3.hotmail.com"

PS:
retVal.Substring(0, 14); doen't work for me, because the server name lenths vary.

thank you! =D

Comment: retVal.Split(' ')[0]

Comment: based on your question retVal contains "mx3.hotmail.com hotmail MX" and obviously there is no way it return "="

Comment: but it return " = ", I don't know why, but it return "="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String.Split(char[], StringSplitOptions)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) to split the string along whitespace:

```
var words = input.Split(new char[] {' ', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If there are any other whitespace characters in the input like new lines ('\n') then you can add them in to the separator array. If this list is likely to change make it configurable.

Then if you know which word you want and if that'll never change:

```
if (words.Length > elementNo) result = words[elementNo];
```

If the word could be anywhere on the list you'll need to scan each word until you find the one you want.

Comment: it work " var words = retVal.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);  "

Comment: before you edit you answaer it was work, after you edit the answaer, it dons't work

Comment: I'm using the first anwaer

Comment: @ItaloJosé which edit? I didn't change the code with my latest edit, only the first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the entire output into a single multiline string, read it line by line and check if you've reached the desired line. Makes use of `Substring()` a walk in the park since you can just read to the end of the line:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c nslookup -type=mx gmail.com"; // Note the /c command (*)
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.Start();

string mx = "";
string delimiter = "mail exchanger = ";

string outputLine;
while ((outputLine = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (outputLine.Contains(delimiter))
        mx = outputLine.Substring(outputLine.IndexOf(delimiter) + delimiter.Length);
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mx))
    Console.WriteLine("Lookup failed");
else
    Console.Write(mx);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's common to use regular expressions for jobs like these, so you might also try something like:

```
// this will match anything after the last '=', before the newline
var regex = new Regex(@"MX preference = \d+, mail exchanger = (?<server>.*)\r\n");

// get the first match
var firstMatch = regex.Match(output);

// print the captured value
Console.WriteLine(firstMatch.Groups["server"].Value);
```

It's also simple to get multiple matches:

```
// get all matches
var matches = regex.Matches(output);
foreach (Match m in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["server"].Value);
```